# How to Read the data from excel sheet and register Multiple account using selenium

Tags: selenium, webdriver

i have to register more account for my web site, For that i have to read the data from excel sheet and input the values using selenium web driver . can some one help.

Comment: Please can you put valid question . or show ur work?

Answer (score -1):

You are going to require some framework to extract data from Excel properly. Selenium is a webdriver, not a data processing framework. If you use java/c# combined with selenium, the solution would be easy.

Comment: Have you even tried to code it? Or research how to make it happen? This isn't a website for someone else to do your work for you.

Comment: http://jexcelapi.sourceforge.net/ Here you go. All required documentation is on this site.